# Keeping same view of 3dplot with plot_ly in R

Tags: r, view, camera, plotly

I have this dataset:

```
> readData

   time             X             Y             Z
1     0        0.0000        0.0000        0.0000
2    29        0.2179       -0.0952        9.9940
3  1028        0.2185       -0.0748        9.9599
4  2029        0.2269       -0.0958        9.9623
5  3029        0.2598       -0.0275       10.1053
6  4029       -0.3154        5.1272        8.3127
7  5029        0.2107        9.5942        1.7274
8  6029       -0.7213        9.8049        1.2252
9  7029       -0.0198        9.1494       -3.3776
10 8029       -0.2472        6.0543       -7.5669
```

I want to plot the vector(X, Y, Z) of each row having the same view for each output.

Based on this previous question: [How to specify camera perspective of 3d plotly chart in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178381/how-to-specify-camera-perspective-of-3d-plotly-chart-in-r)

Here is what I have tried:

```
for (ind in 1:length(readData)
{
  x <- c(0, readData$X[ind])
  y <- c(0, readData$Y[ind])
  z <- c(0, readData$Z[ind])
  scene = list(camera = list(eye = list(x=2, y=2, z=0.1), center=list(x=0, y=0, z=0), up=list(x=0, y=0, z=1)))
  p <- plot_ly(x=x, y=y, z=z, type="scatter3d") %>% 
    layout(title = "3D Scatter plot", scene = scene)
  print(p)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Unfortunately, I still end up having different view of the camera for my plot.

What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: in readData$X[ind], what's "ind"?

Comment: I am iterating on the rows of my data frame. "ind" is my index of my for loop to access the element of each column at row ind.