# create a video from plotly 3d chart

Tags: r, plotly

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to export plotly 3d charts as a video (more specifically if this can be done natively or requires bodging)?

Exporting a static image is simple, and exporting the interactive plots is fine for embedding in HTML etc.

Lets say I have a 3D chart that I want so simply rotate slowly, this seems like it could be pretty straight forward if the image can be rotated a given interval, an image taken, rotated further *ad infinitum*, perhaps in a loop - but I'm wondering if this isn't somehow supported natively?

Anyone know of a good strategy?

Solution ideally for R/RStudio, but since plotly is cross-platform, any solutions considered.

Comment: While downvoting the question is perfectly legitimate...I'd appreciate it if a constructive comment as to why that is needed was provided...

Comment: you could take a look at the `caTools` package. I don't think it works with plotly but you can use it to make gifs.

Comment: I did not downvote but I guess the reason is that your question looks like a google search could fix. There are many packages that can create animations from plots: package `rgl` with `movie3d`, and package `gganimate`. Both rely on imagemagick, so you may have to install this too.

Comment: I have searched for solutions to this, including trawling the plotly webpages. I only ever post a question on SO when google hasn't turned up an answer (or I've not been able to find it).
In this particular case I'm asking whether someone who is perhaps more familiar with plotly knows of some bespoke function, so I don't think its really a case of "let me google that for you"...the downvotes seemed a bit premature and uneccessary.
I'll look in to `gganimate` though thanks, that sounds promising with plotlys dependence on ggplot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference:

The key to being able to iterate multiple perspectives turns out to lie in the camera control "eye", the plotly help centre pointed me toward this:

https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-camera

```
camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.25, y = 1.25, z = 1.25))) #1.25 is default
```

This is kind of answered here, though searching for my specific query as above didn't find it:

[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178381/how-to-specify-camera-perspective-of-3d-plotly-chart-in-r)

I've used a for loop in the script to pass iterators to a trigonometric function that plots out a circle for the camera co-ordinates, rendering a new image at each step.

*(x,y) = cos(theta) + sin(theta)*

[image]

The eventual code looked like this:

```
# assume dataset read in, manipulated and given as a matrix in "matrix"
matrix.list <- list(x = temp, y = scan, z = matrix)

font.pref <- list(size=12, family="Arial, sans-serif", color="black")

x.list <- list(title = "X", titlefont = font.pref)
y.list <- list(title = "Y", titlefont = font.pref)
z.list <- list(title = "Z",titlefont = font.pref)

zoom <- 2

for(i in seq(0,6.3,by=0.1){
# 6.3 is enough for a full 360 rotation

 outfile <- paste(file,"plot",i, sep = "_")
 graph <- plot_ly(matrix.list, x = temp, y = scan, z = z,
                  type="surface") %>%
                  layout(scene=list(xaxis = x.list,
                                    yaxis = y.list,
                                    zaxis = z.list,
                                    camera = list(eye = list(x = cos(i)*zoom, y = sin(i)*zoom, z= 0.25))))

# The above camera parameters should orbit 
# horizontally around the chart.
# The multiplier controls how far out from
# from the graph centre the camera is (so 
# is functionally a 'zoom' control).

  graph
  plotly_IMAGE(graph, username="xxx", key="xxx",
               out_file = paste(outfile,"png", sep="."))
}
```

**NB** Number of files and the resolution of them could end up taking up a fair amount of space.

**NB 2** I had forgotten while constructing this that plotly's free API limits you to 50 API calls per day, so if you want to render a video, adjust your frames etc, accordingly...